# Display nested contents by using customized content types in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, content-type

I have created content type with product_name, product_description, button_name and link. Now i want to display those details as i wanted. How to display nested contents by using customized content types in Drupal7?

Comment: When you say 'as I wanted' do you mean the markup around the fields? The order of the field? You can take a look in the manage display tab of the content type for a little control over the labels and the order of the field. For more control over the markup use a tpl file. If you want to format the data you'll have to use a field formatter.

Comment: yes. It means markup with those fields

Comment: Then you should explore rishabh318' answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to crate template file for your custom content type. which naming convention will be:

```
node--contenttype.tpl.php
```

IN the above you can fetch all fields. eg:

```
<?php print render($content['field_machine_name']); ?>
```

Comment: You should include where to put this file in your example. Ex: sites/all/theme/my_theme/template. You should also explain that this answer take for granted that you have a custom theme